# How to check how much space is available on block device disk (e.g not used on partition)

Tags: disk-usage, disk, lsblk

I have multiple block devices: e.g sda (sda1, sda2 & sda3).
sda3 is further divided into LVMs which all has a X amount of space on them. However, I want to be able to list how much space is available on the sda3, by that I mean, space that's not been used on any LVM partitioning. `df -h` doesn't give the desired result, as it will only give me the LVMs, and not how much space is available on the sda3. Same goes for `lsblk` as it'll only show how big the sda3 partition is.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` will tell you the entire size of the drive, but you will need to subtract the used space from that.

Comment: @Panki, then I could just run `df -h` and open a calculator.

Comment: `df` shows filesystems, not *disks*. That's a difference.

Comment: Sounds like you want `pvs /dev/sda3`.

Comment: `pvs`, I mean pvs gives me the ability to check how much is used and available based on calculating the PE size. To it'll be PE size (MiB) * Free PE.

Comment: It's (by default) giving me `PSize` and `PFree` in `g` (GiB) here.